# Create/delete files without changing directory's modified date

Tags: date, journaling

I want to remove a number of files, *without* touching the containing directories' modified date.

I know I can simply stat the directory in question first, take a note of the modified time, and then manually reset it with `touch -d` after I'm done, but that seems unnecessarily cumbersome.

Specifically, I'm hoping to get an answer to two questions:

1. Is it possible to temporarily 'freeze' the updating of changed/modified/access dates (either on a per-directory basis or for the whole filesystem)?
2. Is it possible to execute a command (in this case the `rm` command) with some kind of flag specifying that modified dates are not to be changed during this command)?

Comment: There is an option in the filesystem to tell the kernel to not update the file dates. I've never tried, just like that, it seems to be a crazy idea... especially if you have hundreds of processes running simultaneously doing things which you probably want to track properly...

Comment: Cross-posted on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1294139/1127743).